# Regular expression to find last colon after timestamp

Tags: python, regex

I have a text string of the following format:

```
[0:00:02] name1: Okay, this is the continued string...
```

I would like to get a python regular expression that extracts all the text starting with `Okay...`

I have figured out how to extract the time stamp and speaker name:

```
 time_frame = re.search('\[(.*?)\]', temp).group(1)
 speaker_id = re.search('\] (.*?)\:', temp).group(1)
```

However, am having no luck with the last one. Note that there could be a colon in the text string to the right but I would want to capture everything in the text string.

Comment: I there a particular problem with just appending `\s*(.*)` to the `speaker_id` pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic:

```py
re.search(r'\[.*?\]\s*\w+:\s*(.+)', temp).group(1)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/fdRBTk/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]                       ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude matching the `:`, then match it and optional whitespace chars. Then capture all that follows in a capturing group.

```
^\[[^][]*][^:]*:\s*(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5GV1Eu/1)

```
import re

regex = r"^\[[^][]*][^:]*:\s*(.+)"
temp = "[0:00:02] name1: Okay, this is the continued string..."
matches = re.search(regex, temp)

if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Output

```
Okay, this is the continued string...
```

---

Matching all 3 parts in a single pattern:

```
^\[([^][]*)]([^:]*):\s*(.+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^\[` Match opening `[` at the start of the string
- `([^][]*)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except `[` and `]`
- `]\s*` Match closing `]`
- `([^:]*)` Capture **group 2** Match any char except `:`
- `:\s*` Match `:` and 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.+)` Capture **group 3**, Match the rest of the string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Us2QqP/1)

```
import re

regex = r"^\[([^][]*)]\s*([^:]*):\s*(.+)"
temp = "[0:00:02] name1: Okay, this is the continued string..."
matches = re.search(regex, temp)

if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
    print(matches.group(2))
    print(matches.group(3))
```

Output

```
0:00:02
name1
Okay, this is the continued string...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can literally match the timestamp with `\[\d+:\d+:\d+\]` and the first colon with `.*?:`

```
'\[\d+:\d+:\d+\].*?:(.*)'
```

You can actually match all your 3 groups with one regex:

```
'\[(\d+:\d+:\d+\)] (.*?):(.*)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us get all together in a simple way `g=re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]\s*(.*):\s*(.*)',text)`

```
import re

text='[0:00:02] name1: Okay, this is the continued string...'

g=re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]\s*(.*):\s*(.*)',text)

time_frame = g[0][0]
speaker_id = g[0][1]
speach = g[0][2]

print(time_frame)
print(speaker_id)
print(speach)
```

output

```
0:00:02
name1
Okay, this is the continued string...
```